# Missing Gremlin methods and types in typescript types package

Tags: typescript-typings, gremlin

I'm working with gremlin 3.5.2 and have the types dependency on:

```
"@types/gremlin": "^3.5.2"
```

But the tx() method isn't defined on the GraphTraversalSource.
I see the method is defined in the gremlin code, so I'm guessing this is only a lack of typescript type definition.
How do I get the updated types for this version?